# how to add var label on top of col name

Tags: r

I have two data.frame, one for data (df), one for var label (vl).
[image]

How can I join them together and get sth looks like following:
[image]

Sample data df and vl can be build using codes:

```
df<-structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), Date = c("Day 1", 
"Day 7", "Day 29", "Day_8", "Day9", "Day7", "Day.1", "Day 21"
), Score = c("A", "B", "E", "D", "F", "G", "A", "B"), Pass = c("Y", 
"Y", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

vl <-structure(list(Var = c("ID", "Score", "Pass", "Date"), Label = c("Subject ID", 
"Exam Score", "Pass or Fail the Exam", "Exam Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, dataframes cannot have double column names so one way would to shift your original column names as first row.

```
setNames(rbind(names(df), df), vl$Label[match(names(df), vl$Var)])

#  `Subject ID` `Exam Date` `Exam Score` `Pass or Fail the Exam`
#  <chr>        <chr>       <chr>        <chr>                  
#1 ID           Date        Score        Pass                   
#2 1            Day 1       A            Y                      
#3 1            Day 7       B            Y                      
#4 1            Day 29      E            N                      
#5 2            Day_8       D            Y                      
#6 2            Day9        F            N                      
#7 3            Day7        G            N                      
#8 3            Day.1       A            Y                      
#9 3            Day 21      B            Y
```

Comment: It's worth warning that this means the dataset is now all but unusable for analysis.

Comment: Yep - perhaps adding an "attribute" to the data frame, which contains these variable labels, may be an alternative. But that depends on the objectives. Ronak's answer does what the OP asked.

Comment: @Ronak Shah Thanks for the suggestion. What if I have a list  `lst1` that contain multiple data.frame. What should I do in order to apply the same method to all of them?

Comment: Use `lapply` on `lst1` and use the same code inside the function.

Comment: @Ronak Shah do you mean `lapply (lst1, setNames(rbind(names(lst[[]]), lst1[[]]]), ...])`? Could you explain a little bit more with example. I have some difficulty understanding how to pass this through a list. Thanks.

Comment: Use an anonymous function `lapply(list_df, function(df) setNames(rbind(names(df), df), vl$Label[match(names(df), vl$Var)]))`